# jQuery UI progressbar on a timer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, settimeout

I have a progressbar on the top of my page that I'm using to display the 1 minute timer used to refresh all the charts.  The problem I'm having is that it never seems to be consistent.

```
function headerBar() {
    var progressbar = $('#timerBar');
    progressbar.progressbar({
        value: 0
    });

    function progress() {
        var val = progressbar.progressbar('value') || 0;
        progressbar.progressbar('value', val + 5);
        if (val < 99) {
            setTimeout(progress, 3000);
        }
    }
    progress();
}
headerBar();
  setInterval(function () {
     headerBar();
  }, 60 * 1000);
```

The first time it runs fine, but the 2nd time seems to take 1/2 as long and every time after that seems to shave off time from the count.

here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybolanos/w3QB7/)

Comment: put your setInterval function after the call to the function progress in the headerbar function

Comment: The setInterval function runs all the code to get the JSON and update the charts so it needs to be stand alone.  I need the headerBar() function to reset the timer completely so the setTImeout function doesn't stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hurray! You're running into a kind-of race condition. Since `setTimeout()` does not guarantee to call every 3000ms like `setInterval()` (and even if it did, you'd still be subject to this problem), what most likely happens is that your interval calls `headerBar()` before `progress()` manages to stop itself from adding more timeouts! Here's a timeline to clear this up:

*Your progressbar is at 95!*

`timeout1` -> I better call `progress()`!

`progress()` -> Set progress bar to `val + 5 = 100`! `val(95) < 99` ? Yeah! I better set a timeout to call myself again

`interval` -> Thy time is up! `headerBar()`!

`headerBar()` -> I set the progress to 0, and start more `progress()`!

`progress()` -> Set progress bar to 5! Timeout to call myself again!

`progress()` -> Set progress bar to 10! Timeout to call myself again! (Oops, I never got to `val > 99` to stop calling myself repeatedly!)

time passes...

`interval` -> It's time to go FASTER! `headerBar()`!

But how do you solve this problem? Well, firstly, you'll want to change your `progress()` check to use `val + 5 < 99`. That still won't save you from problems like calling 20 timeouts taking longer than your one interval - you'll need some way to signal your `progress()` to stop with all the progressing.

One way to do this would be to add some sanity checks to `headerBar()`:

```
function headerBar() {
    var progressbar = $('#timerBar');
    var lastProgress = 0;
    progressbar.progressbar({
        value: lastProgress
    });

    function progress() {
        var val = progressbar.progressbar('value') || 0;
        if (val != lastProgress) {
            // Someone's modified the bar! I best stop before I do too much progress!
            return;
        }
        progressbar.progressbar('value', val + 5);
        if (val + 5 < 99) {
            setTimeout(progress, 3000);
        }
    }
    progress();
}
```

This is a very hacky solution, however. A much more elegant one would be to use a closure!

```
var headerBar = (function () {
    var inProgress = false;
    var progressbar = $('#timerBar'); // Save some trees by calling jQuery selection only once!
    return function headerBar() {
        if (inProgress) {
            clearTimeout(inProgress);
            inProgress = false;
        }
        progressbar.progressbar({
            value: 0
        });
        function progress() {
            var val = progressbar.progressbar('value') || 0;
            progressbar.progressbar('value', val + 5);
            if (val < 99) {
                inProgress = setTimeout(progress, 3000);
            }
        }
        progress();
    }
})();
```

In general though, you could still work on eliminating your interval(this would introduce a slight error in your timing), by modifying `headerBar()` to simply tell you when it's done.

```
// Pass the jQuery element so you not only have to select it once, but don't depend on the headerBar knowing where to look for it.
var headerBar = (function (progressbar) {
    return function headerBar(callback) {
        progressbar.progressbar({ value : 0 });
        (function progress() {
            var newVal = (progressbar.progressbar('value') || 0) + 5;
            progressbar.progressbar('value', newVal);
            if (newVal < 99) setTimeout(progress, 3000);
            else callback();
        })();
    }
})($('#timerBar'));

function heavyLifting() {
    // get stuff, etc
    headerBar(heavyLifting);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3QB7/1/)

```
(function () {
    var progressbar;

    function headerBar() {
        progressbar = $('#timerBar');
        progressbar.progressbar({
            value: 0
        });

        function progress() {
            var val = progressbar.progressbar('value') || 0;
            progressbar.progressbar('value', val + 5);
            if (val < 99) {
                setTimeout(progress, 3000);
            }
        }
        progress();
    }
    headerBar();
    setInterval(function () {
        progressbar.progressbar('value', 0);
    }, 60 * 1000);
})();
```

Comment: The setInterval has a lot to do - I need the progress bar to reset when it starts for a new minute.  The setInterval isn't just for the progressbar but the progressbar must sync up to what the setInterval is doing.

Comment: i love js fiddle ! thanks for the code i searched for free countdown timer in jquery and this is what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

you need a clear interval.. like this

```
function headerBar() {
    var progressbar = $('#timerBar');
    progressbar.progressbar({
        value: 0
    });

    function progress() {
        var val = progressbar.progressbar('value') || 0;
        progressbar.progressbar('value', val + 5);
        if (val < 99) {
            setTimeout(progress, 3000);
        }
    }
    progress();
    clearInterval()
}
headerBar();
setInterval(function () {
        headerBar();
    }, 60 * 1000);
```

More examples of setTimeout on SitePoint [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/)

Comment: I can't clear the interval because the setInterval is running a mess of code every 60 seconds - I need the progressbar to reset each time the setInterval loops

Comment: whhy are you calling header bar twice anyway?

Comment: The first time (before the setInterval) starts the first 60 sec progress - when it finishes is when the first setInterval loop is called.  the setInterval doesn't run any of its code until 60 seconds after the page loads so the progressbar needs to show this time too

Comment: thanks, I needed to come here so someone could tell me I have a problem when I'm asking for help with my problem.

Comment: have a look at this question i think it will help loads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690465/using-settimeout-to-update-progress-bar-when-looping-over-multiple-variables

Comment: @RachelGallen Please be aware that the documentation link will be non-functional in the near future, which is why I made the edit removing the link.