# jquery countdown/timer line script needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to put a countdown/timer script in my page which visually warns a user how much time is left to perform a certain action (i.e. edit a post) - I'd like the user to see a line that gets smaller by the second, indicating that an action can no longer be performed when the line is not visible.

Ideally, as inputs, the script would take the number of time units remaining, the units in which time is measured, the color and initial width of the line, and whether the line should be vertical or horizontal. It would be ideal if the line could be placed so that it overlays the edge of DIV.

Does anyone have a script which fulfills most or all of the functionality specified above? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using the jQuery Progressbar? http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Thanks - I'll keep it under consideration as an option.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740136/jquery-ui-progressbar-on-a-timer