# Javascript: How to update a progress bar in a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript

I am have an issue with a JS script I am trying to put together.  I have an HTML table with somewhere in the neighborhood of 300 rows in it.  I have made a sort function that will make the table headers clickable and launch my sort function. I would like to integrate a progress bar because in larger tables (500 - 1000 rows) after a header is clicked the table takes a bit of time to sort (IE is a big offender). The progress bar would tell them how much time remains before the sort is complete.  The method I had in mind was a div element that I would resize based on the progression of the sort loop. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to integrate such a routine into my loop.

I've researched the issue and taken note of this: [How to change progress bar in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774245/how-to-change-progress-bar-in-loop)
and this: [Using setTimeout to update progress bar when looping over multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690465/using-settimeout-to-update-progress-bar-when-looping-over-multiple-variables)

The second topic has a few demos that do essentially what I would like to do as far as the progress bar goes.  However, anytime I try to implement the solutions shown in those two posts I either:

A - Crash the browser

B - Progress bar appears to work, but goes from 0 - 100% instantly, not progressively.

I am hoping someone can lead me in the right direction on what to do.  This table sort progress indicator must be done using native JS because the contents must be available offline, hence I can't include any jQuery libraries via CDN and bloating the document with the entire jQuery library isn't desired.

I've created a JS fiddle with my code in it.  I've stripped out what I had for progress bar code because I kept crashing the browser so all that is there as far as scripts go is the sorting-related code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnBmp/3/)

Here is the JS itself:

```
//Change this variable to match the "id" attribute of the
//table that is going to be operated on.
var tableID = "sortable";

/**
 * Attach click events to all the <th> elements in a table to 
 * call the tableSort() function. This function assumes that cells  
 * in the first row in a table are <th> headers tags and that cells
 * in the remaining rows are <td> data tags.
 *
 * @param table The table element to work with.
 * @return void
 */
function initHeaders(table) {
    //Get the table element
    table = document.getElementById(table);
    //Get the number of cells in the header row
    var l = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    //Loop through the header cells and attach the events
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if(table.rows[0].cells[i].addEventListener) { //For modern browsers
            table.rows[0].cells[i].addEventListener("click", tableSort, false);
        } else if(table.rows[0].cells[i].attachEvent) { //IE specific method
            table.rows[0].cells[i].attachEvent("onclick", tableSort);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Compares values in a column of a table and then sorts the table rows.
 * Subsequent calls to this function will toggle a row between ascending
 * and descending sort directions.
 *
 * @param e The click event passed in from the browser.
 * @return mixed No return value if operation completes successfully, FALSE on error.
 */
function tableSort(e) { 

    /**
     * Checks to see if a value is numeric.
     *
     * @param n The incoming value to check.
     * @return bool TRUE if value is numeric, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    tableSort.isNumeric = function (n) {
        var num = false;
        if(!isNaN(n) && isFinite(n)) {
            num = true;
        }
        return num;
    }

    //Get the element from the click event that was passed.
    if(e.currentTarget) { //For modern browsers
        e = e.currentTarget;
    } else if(window.event.srcElement) { //IE specific method
        e = window.event.srcElement;
    } else {
        console.log("Unable to determine source event. Terminating....");
        return false;
    }

    //Get the index of the cell, will be needed later
    var ndx = e.cellIndex;

    //Toggle between "asc" and "desc" depending on element's id attribute
    if(e.id == "asc") {
        e.id = "desc";
    } else {
        e.id = "asc";
    }

    //Move up from the <th> that was clicked and find the parent table element.
    var parent = e.parentElement;
    var s = parent.tagName;
    while(s.toLowerCase() != "table") {
        parent = parent.parentElement;
        s = parent.tagName;
    }

    /*
    Executes two different loops.  A "for" loop to control how many
    times the table rows are passed looking for values to sort and a
    "while" loop that does the actual comparing of values.  The "for"
    loop also controls how many times the embedded "while" loop will
    run since each iteration with force at least one table row into 
    the correct position.   
    */

    //var interval = setInterval( function () { progress.updateProgress() } , 100);
    var rows = parent.tBodies[0].rows.length; //Isolate and count rows only in the <tbody> element.
    if(rows > 1) {  //Make sure there are enough rows to bother with sorting
        var v1; //Value 1 placeholder
        var v2; //Value 2 placeholder
        var tbody = parent.tBodies[0];  //Table body to manipulate
        //Start the for loop (controls amount of table passes)
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            var j = 0;  //Counter for swapping routine
            var offset = rows - i - 1;  //Stops next loop from overchecking

            // WANT TO UPDATE PROGRESS BAR HERE

            //Start the while loop (controls number of comparisons to make)
            while(j < offset) {             

                //Check to make sure values can be extracted before proceeding
                if(typeof tbody.rows[j].cells[ndx].innerHTML !== undefined && typeof tbody.rows[j + 1].cells[ndx].innerHTML !== undefined) {

                    //Get cell values and compare
                    v1 = tbody.rows[j].cells[ndx].innerHTML;
                    v2 = tbody.rows[j + 1].cells[ndx].innerHTML;
                    if(tableSort.isNumeric(v1) && tableSort.isNumeric(v2)) {
                        //Dealing with two numbers
                        v1 = new Number(v1);
                        v2 = new Number(v2);
                        if(v1 > v2) {
                            if(e.id == "asc") { //v1 moves down
                                tbody.insertBefore(tbody.rows[j + 1], tbody.rows[j]);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if(e.id == "desc") { //v1 moves down
                                tbody.insertBefore(tbody.rows[j + 1], tbody.rows[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(tableSort.isNumeric(v1) && !tableSort.isNumeric(v2)) {
                        //v2 is a string, v1 is a number and automatically wins
                        if(e.id == "asc") { //v1 moves down
                            tbody.insertBefore(tbody.rows[j + 1], tbody.rows[j]);
                        }
                    } else if(!tableSort.isNumeric(v1) && tableSort.isNumeric(v2)) {
                        //v1 is a string, v2 is a number and automatically wins
                        if(e.id == "desc") { //v1 moves down
                            tbody.insertBefore(tbody.rows[j + 1], tbody.rows[j]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Both v1 and v2 are strings, use localeCompare()
                        if(v1.localeCompare(v2) > 0) {
                            if(e.id == "asc") { //v1 moves down
                                tbody.insertBefore(tbody.rows[j + 1], tbody.rows[j]);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if(e.id == "desc") { //v1 moves down
                                tbody.insertBefore(tbody.rows[j + 1], tbody.rows[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                } else {
                    console.log("One of the values turned up undefined");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Wait until DOM is ready and then initialize the table headers.
window.onload = function () {
    initHeaders(tableID);
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

**-----
EDIT:
-----** Okay so after reading the answers here and making some hefty modifications to how I was going about things I have come up with a much better solution.  The progress bar isn't exactly what I wanted, but it is close.  (Although I believe that it is showing up on the page just as the sorting is getting ready to finish up.)

I modified my loop to do a O(n log n) quick sort and instead of modifying the DOM directly I instead isolate the table rows to sort and copy them into an array.  I then do the sort directly on the array and once it is finished I rebuild the rows and then remove the old rows and append the new ones in.  The sort time has been reduced significantly.

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/jnBmp/5/

And here is the new JS code:

```
//Change this variable to match the "id" attribute of the
//table that is going to be operated on.
var tableID = "sortable";

/**
 * Attach click events to all the <th> elements in a table to 
 * call the tableSort() function. This function assumes that cells  
 * in the first row in a table are <th> headers tags and that cells
 * in the remaining rows are <td> data tags.
 *
 * @param table The table element to work with.
 * @return void
 */
function initHeaders(table) {
    //Get the table element
    table = document.getElementById(table);
    //Get the number of cells in the header row
    var l = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    //Loop through the header cells and attach the events
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if(table.rows[0].cells[i].addEventListener) { //For modern browsers
            table.rows[0].cells[i].addEventListener("click", tableSort, false);
        } else if(table.rows[0].cells[i].attachEvent) { //IE specific method
            table.rows[0].cells[i].attachEvent("onclick", tableSort);
        }
    }
}


function tableSort(e) { 

    var runs = 0;
    var pix = 0;
    var ndx = 0;
    var dir = "right";
    var interval = false;

    //Get the element from the click event that was passed.
    if(e.currentTarget) { //For modern browsers
        e = e.currentTarget;
    } else if(window.event.srcElement) { //IE specific method
        e = window.event.srcElement;
    } else {
        console.log("Unable to determine source event. Terminating....");
        return false;
    }

    //Get the index of the cell, will be needed later
    ndx = e.cellIndex;

    //Toggle between "asc" and "desc" depending on element's id attribute
    if(e.id == "asc") {
        e.id = "desc";
    } else {
        e.id = "asc";
    }

    //Move up from the <th> that was clicked and find the parent table element.
    var parent = e.parentElement;
    var s = parent.tagName;
    while(s.toLowerCase() != "table") {
        parent = parent.parentElement;
        s = parent.tagName;
    }

    //Get the rows to operate on as an array
    var rows = document.getElementById("replace").rows;
    var a = new Array();
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        a.push(rows[i]);
    }

    //Show progress bar ticker
    document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "block";

    /**
     * Show the progress bar ticker animation
     *
     * @param pix The current pixel count to set the <div> margin at.
     */
    function updateTicker(pix) {

                var tick = document.getElementById("progressTicker");
                document.getElementById("progressText").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("progressText").innerHTML = "Sorting table...please wait";
                if(dir == "right") {
                    if(pix < 170) {
                        pix += 5;
                        tick.style.marginLeft = pix + "px";
                    } else {
                        dir = "left";
                    }
                } else {
                    if(pix > 0) {
                        pix -= 5;
                        tick.style.marginLeft = pix + "px";
                    } else {
                        dir = "left";
                    }
                }
                interval = window.setTimeout( function () { updateTicker(pix); }, 25);
    }
    updateTicker(pix);

    /**
     * Checks to see if a value is numeric.
     *
     * @param n The incoming value to check.
     * @return bool TRUE if value is numeric, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    isNumeric = function (n) {
        var num = false;
        if(!isNaN(n) && isFinite(n)) {
            num = true;
        }
        return num;
    }

    /**
     * Compares two values and determines which one is "bigger".
     *
     * @param x A reference value to check against.
     * @param y The value to be determined bigger or smaller than the reference.
     * @return TRUE if y is greater or equal to x, FALSE otherwise
     */
    function compare(x, y) {
        var bigger = false;
        x = x.cells[ndx].textContent;
        y = y.cells[ndx].textContent;
        //console.log(e.id);
        if(isNumeric(x) && isNumeric(y)) {
            if(y >= x) {
                bigger = (e.id == "asc") ? true : false;
            } else {                
                bigger = (e.id == "desc") ? true : false;
            }
        } else {
            if(y.localeCompare(x) >= 0) {
                bigger = (e.id == "asc") ? true : false;
            } else {                
                bigger = (e.id == "desc") ? true : false;
            }
        }
        return bigger;
    }   

    /**
     * Performs a quicksort O(n log n) on an array.
     *
     * @param array The array that needs sorting
     * @return array The sorted array.
     */
    function nlognSort(array) {
        runs++
        if(array.length > 1) {
            var big = new Array();
            var small = new Array();
            var pivot = array.pop();
            var l = array.length;
            for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if(compare(pivot,array[i])) {
                    big.push(array[i]);
                } else {
                    small.push(array[i]);
                }
            }
            return Array.prototype.concat(nlognSort(small), pivot, nlognSort(big));
        } else {
            return array;
        }
    }


    //Run sort routine  
    b = nlognSort(a);

    //Rebuild <tbody> and replace new with the old
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    var l = b.length;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        tbody.appendChild(b.shift());
    }
    parent.removeChild(document.getElementById("replace"));
    parent.appendChild(tbody);
    tbody.setAttribute("id","replace");
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("progress").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("progressText").style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(interval);
    },1500);
}


window.onload = function() {
    initHeaders(tableID);
}
```

Thanks again everyone!!

Comment: At first I'd try to get a faster sort by using the native [`Array::sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with `O(n log n)`, your current algorithm has `O(n²)`. Only if that doesn't help, you would have to write your own fast and asynchronous sort function (which seems a little over your head, judged from the current code quality).

Comment: Don't sort the DOM in-place. While JavaScript itself can sort quite fast, DOM access can be quite slow, especially on older browsers!

Comment: it's just too slow to both rearrange and update a progress bar. you might trying setting visibility:hidden on the table while sorting, that can avoid redraws, and greatly speed up the operation under certain conditions.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the tip about the sorting. A look around the internet and wikipedia gave me the info I needed to write up what is hopefully a good implementation of the quick sort. On a side note, I am still getting myself familiar with JS and what goes on under the hood, could you elaborate on what you meant about the current code quality?  I didn't take offense to the comment, but was curious if there was something unorthodox I was/am doing.  http://jsfiddle.net/jnBmp/5/

Comment: @HallvarHelleseth Thanks for the info about DOM access.  I didn't realize how slow editing the DOM directly could be, and how shoddy looking rearranging rows would be in a loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the following:
http://jsfiddle.net/6JxQk/

The idea here is to replace your for loop with an asynchronous loop that uses `setTimeout()`, so you would go from the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

... to this:

```
var i = 0;
(function doSort() {
    // update progress
    // do stuff
    i++;
    if (i < rows) {
        setTimeout(doSort, 0);
    }
})();
```

Although as you can see, this significantly slows down your sorting routine because in addition to updating the progress bar, this will reorder the rows of your table.  With this in mind I think you are better off just using a built-in sort rather than your own implementation, and dropping the progress bar.

Comment: +1, here's a version with updated UI (the CSS that was intended to be used by OP): http://jsfiddle.net/6JxQk/1/

Comment: This is the only portable solution I know of, however isn't this scenario what the yield() construct is intended to support too? (not yet portable)

Comment: @F.J The setTimeout() method was a good start.  The working examples you and Bergi showed me gave some insight on where I was going wrong about my implementation.  I decided to go with a progress bar that isn't dependent on a sentinel based loop.  However your answer still provided a progress bar much like I wanted.

Comment: @Andrew_Clark How would you go about doing this for a `.map()` or `.reduce()` or some other such Javascript array operation? Is there a trick to make it work and still retain the original array method, or will it have to be rewritten like you did with the `for` loop above?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for - IMHO a progress bar must be used when you have an estimate of how much time a particular operation is going to take or how many bytes need to be transferred. In other non-deterministic cases you must be showing a spinner :-)

Comment: A sort operation is quite deterministic I'd say - unless it's an adaptive sort, then you'd need to measure the presortedness in before.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get the statement - A sort operation is quite deterministic - are you saying here that an algorithm will sort exactly in X.YYY seconds irrespective of the machine it is running on ?

Comment: Nope. Neither as you you know how fast the connection will be when transmitting a known number of bytes. But you can show a proportional bar that says something like "*30% of elements are sorted*"