# How to Increase a progress bar in Angularjs loop

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar

I'm learning angularjs and I am having some problems with increasing progress bar during a loop.

I'll explain better. I have the modal with checkbox of all months, like the ones shown on the website below

http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

So, I can choose one or more months to obtain data.

The html code is

```
 <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="calendar" ng-change="keepMonths()">All
    <div ng-repeat="month in months">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="choose.selected" checklist-value="month"> {{month.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button name="Export" ng-click="exportExcel()" class="upButton">Export</button>
    <div class="demo-section k-content" style="width: 350px;">
        <h4>{{status}}</h4>
        <div kendo-progress-bar="progressBar" k-min="0" k-max="100" ng-model="progress"></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

If I click in export button it realy works fine, but I want to put a progress bar, because the processing of the months takes a lot of time and I wish the User follow the processing of data, so I try to do this:

```
   $scope.exportExcel = function () {

    $scope.status = "Processing...";  // it doesn't work
    $scope.$apply($scope.status);  // it doesn't work

    var data = []
    var Increase = $scope.choose.selected.length / 100

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.choose.selected.length; i++) {
        startDate = new Date("01/01/2015 00:00:00"; //for example
        endDate = new Date("31/01/2015 23:59:59"; //for example

            MUSTService.GetExcel($rootScope.empreendimento, $rootScope.pontoconexao, postohorario, dataInicio, // GetExcel goes to code behind and returns a json (dados) with all data of that month
            function (dados) {
                data = $scope.concatDados(dados, data);  // concatDados is responsible for concatenate all data from months in one variable (data)
            }, null, dataFim);  

        $scope.progress = $scope.progress + Increase; // it doesn't work
        $scope.$apply($scope.progress); // it doesn't work
        $scope.progress = 20; // it doesn't work (for test)
        $scope.$apply($scope.progress); //  it doesn't work (for test)
    }

    // the code below is only responsible for downloading the excel
    var query = 'SELECT NomReduzido AS [Empreendimento], NomCurto AS [Ponto de conexão], DinQuinzeminutos AS [Data/Hora], IFNULL(CodOrigem, \'\') AS Origem, ';
    query = query + ' INTO XLSX("MUST_' + $rootScope.empreendimento.trim() + '_' + decodeURI($rootScope.pontoconexao).trim() + '_' + $rootScope.postohorario.trim() + faltante + '.xlsx" , ? ) FROM ?';
    alasql(query, [opts, data]);

    $scope.progress = 20; // it works
    $scope.$apply($scope.progress); // it works
    $scope.status = "concluded..."; // it works
    $scope.$apply($scope.status);   // it works
}
```

If I try to Increase the progress bar, it doesn't work. The progress bar only begin to increase after the end of the for loop, and I don't know why.
I put some comments in the code to help you to understand.

I tried to put something like that inside of the loop, only for a test,  but it doesn't work. However, if I put the same code below outside the loop it works, but what really takes times is the loop part, because of this it's importante to increase there.

```
   $scope.progress = 20;
   $scope.$apply($scope.progress);
```

I even tried to put a image with a message "Loading", but the image still appearing only when the for loop ends.

If someone could help me to show a way to increase a progress bar during the loop or even show a image, I will be grateful

Comment: have you tried printing `$scope.progress` values in for loop? Are they as expected i.e. between 0 to 100 range? Not a NaN or string or something that kendo progress bar doesn't expect?

Comment: also I don't think you need to use `$scope.$apply` for updating the kendo progress bar. As it is a `ng-model` for kendo progress bar, it should auto update when you change `$scope.progress` value

Comment: btw also check the missing semicolons in your code. For eg. `var data` and `var Instance` declarations

Comment: Have you tried  $scope.$apply(function () { <your loop body> });  just checking if an error inside your loop is actually preventing the rest to run

Comment: The problem was because the loop and the prossing were asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.progress` is being set correctly at the correct times in your code. As long as your script is executing synchronously, though, you will never see a repaint that shows the updates on the progress bar itself. In desktop applications, this issue is generally handled by having a UI thread and a worker thread. The UI thread is basically idle, so it happily repaints when it's informed that the progress has incremented. Leaving aside Web Workers for now, JavaScript is single-threaded, so while you're inside that `for` loop, it never goes idle and allows a repaint.

If this progress bar is essential, the far-from-trivial answer is to make your `for` loop asynchronous, using `$timeout`. Even setting the timeout delay to 0 should work.

More information, and an idea of how to proceed, can be found in the 2nd answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690465/using-settimeout-to-update-progress-bar-when-looping-over-multiple-variables) and the accepted answer on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957823/javascript-how-to-update-a-progress-bar-in-a-for-loop).

Comment: Thanks  Kevin, I did like the other Stack that you mentioned and it worked